# Prevent users to drop image files in a shared folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, network-share

I have a folder that is shared on the network. That folder contains a lot of files, documents, images, etc.
I would like that users can put any kind of files in the folder but NO images (JPG).
I can't user FSRM because the folder may contain images files.
I just want to prevent users to copy them there.

Thank you.

Comment: I think FSRM is your only option, unless you can find a third party solution.